# document.変数　の役割

Tags: javascript

document.変数　の役割がわかりません。
http://cya.sakura.ne.jp/java/calc.htm
のサイトを見ながらjavascriptを勉強しています。

```
document.myForm.myLine.value = myInput;
```

の行が何をしているのかがわかりません。
説明には「現在入力している値表示」と書いてありますが、なぜdocument.変数・・・と書けば値がhtmlに表示されるのでしょうか？

documentはWebページを構成しているHTML要素へプログラム上から簡単にアクセスできると調べた時に出てきたのですが、今回の場合だとどのようにアクセスしているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

それは関数 `function myValue(myData)` の定義だけを見ていてもわかりません。
後ろの方に HTML のコードが書いてあると思いますが、そこに `name=myForm` および `name=myLine` というのを探すことができると思います。
`function myValue(myData)` における `myFrom` および `myLine` は HTML のコードのその部分のことを指し示しています。

すなわち、`document.myForm.myLine.value` は HTML の `<form name="myForm">...</form>` 内にある `<input type="text" size="12" name="myLine" value="0">` の値(`value`)を表します。

Answer (score 3):

[`Document`オブジェクト](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-document-object)は[`named properties`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#idl-named-properties)に対応しているため

```
<form name="myForm" ...>
```

が存在する場合に`document.myForm`で当該要素にアクセス可能です。
同様に[`Form`要素](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-form-element)も`named properties`に対応しているため

```
<form name="myForm" ...>
  ...
  <input name="myLine" ... />
  ...
</form>
```

が存在する場合に`document.myForm.myLine`で当該要素にアクセス可能です。